# Labeling arrows in commutative diagrams

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I draw a commutative diagram by following commands, but I was unable to put labels on maps (Arrows). The diagram commands are as below:

```
\begin{center}
\tikzcdset{row sep/normal=2cm}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & H\arrow[ddl, bend right]\arrow[ddr, bend left]\arrow[d, dashed] & \\
 & A\rtimes G \arrow[dl]\arrow[dr] & \\
 A &  & G  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

The diagram appearing is as below. **How to label the arrows here? What modifications in command are to be done?**

[image]

Comment: `ddl, bend right` -> `ddl, bend right, "ab"`, for example.

Comment: What problem I am facing is that, after copying your label **"ab"** it is producing proper output; but if **I type "ab"** with keys for double inverted commas, it is not running. It may be my computer problem.

Comment: Don't use `''` but `"`. They are different characters

Comment: OK; thanks; it is working. Final question, in the two diagonal arrows, if we want to put labels them **both below**, how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the labels are added in the format of `quotes` library, so you must use `"` instead of `''`.

To change the style of labels, you can use option `labels`. This is a short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzcdset{row sep/normal=2cm}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & H\arrow[ddl, bend right]\arrow[ddr, bend left, "xyz"]\arrow[d, dashed] & \\
 & A\rtimes G \arrow[dl,"xyz"]\arrow[dr,"abc",labels=below left] & \\
 A &  & G  
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much to you and stackoverflow too.